# rails validates uniqueness date for specific timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I faced with some specific issue and I don't wanna write custom validation because I know it's possible to do it in rails-way.

So, about the issue:

I need `uniqueness` validation for `created_at` field, for in one day, but this date should be in Pacific Time Zone.

So, only one record in period 7:00AM-7:00AM

Any suggestion, guys?

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps are persisted in UTC and I guess the timezone is not really an issue for you since you just want it to be unique in your DB.

I'd suggest you to add a `created_on` field to your table which will be managed by Activerecord and filled with the current date and validate its uniqueness.

Comment: by default timestamps in `created_at` persisted without timezone and ActiveRecord transform it to local machine's time zone. And I need uniqueness row for specific time zone.